# Are Apple developer account certificate creation/deletion operations logged for Team Agent to view?

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

It came to my notice that the push notification were not getting delivered to the app.
On checking with Developer Account, found that the APNS Certificate for that app was missing in the Apple production account.

I am not the Team Agent, but an Admin. 2 others have admin role.

These I think are the possibilities of for the certificate to disappear.

1. Somebody has revoked the certificate (accidentally) by logging into developer.apple.com.
2. Certificate expiry. Not sure if apple will remove it for us once the certificate expires.
3. If the developer had added the production account in his Xcode, is there an option to revoke the certificate (accidentally) via Xcode itself?

Are there other possible reason for the same?

Are these activities like creation/revoking of certificate and provisioning profile being logged and available for view for atleast the Team Agent?

Or is there any provision by which the Team Agent could configure to recieve alerts via email when certificate creation/revoking is done by developers?

If we are able to trace the cause, we would want to be cautions going forward and avoid such incidents.

Answer (score 0):

No Team Agent will not get any email for certificate creation/deletion.

Somebody has revoked the certificate (accidentally) by logging into developer.apple.com. ==> Yes this will remove your certificate

Certificate expiry. Not sure if apple will remove it for us once the certificate expires. ==> Apple is not removing any certificate automatically.

If the developer had added the production account in his Xcode, is there an option to revoke the certificate (accidentally) via Xcode itself? ==> With Xcode you cannot revoke certificate except if some once is running through terminal command